# iOS NSLocation usage plist

Tags: ios, plist

I'm trying to make an application that requires 'Always' usage of NSLocation and hence wrote such kind of information to info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location authorization requested for ...</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location authorization requested for ...</string>
```

Which both of descriptions are identical

I also added capability of 'Location Updates' for Background Modes but whenever I try to upload the app to app store connect I get such kind of email.

[image]

what could possibly be the reason?

Comment: The user knows that your app wants location permission. The string you provide needs to explain *why* it wants permission.

Comment: Most likely your info.plist is not well formed. [edit] your question to provide these entries in context